# Do I need to write my own validator for xml validation against xsd schema?

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd, schema

I'm trying to support my users in creating an xml based on an xsd (xml schema).
So I show possible elements and the user can add it to an xml.
However, i have problems to determine the possible elements or to validate that what the user adds is correct. How do I check complex elements?

Let's say we have a sequence element. How am I going to check that the user adds an element at the right place? 
Let's say we have a choice element. How am I going to check that an element from the other particle has been added already?

I can validate the xml against the schema in c# but the errors it returns can (maybe) be showed to the user but I can't use them in my code since the format is inappropriate for that and it just doesn't return enough details.

Do I need to write my own validator (and implement all the w3c specs)??

Thanks!

Comment: if you're using visual studio you can use [xsd.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx) to generate validating C# objects, which you can parse with [xmlserializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks, I have looked into that but i want to parse the XSD at runtime. This is not possible with xsd.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to implement your own validator.  `XmlSchemaValidator` will actually give you a good amount of information.  See the answer to my own similar question here : [XML Schemas -- List allowed attributes/tags at position in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6823866/213901)

Comment: @Default hey I can't help it if I have a stuttering problem

Comment: Thanks climbage! This looks promising!