# How can I add an XElement child based on XSD validation rules?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xsd

I would like to add an `XElement` child to a parent `XElement` instance. But, I want the location of the child element to conform to the rules specified in a given XSD. Specifically, I want the child element to cohere to an `<xs:sequence>` rule. It would be nice if I could find a solution that took into account any XSD rules, though.

Is this possible? My initial thought was to loop through each child element that already exists and try adding the new element after, then validate the `XDocument`, and continue this in a loop until there are no validation errors. But is there a better way to do this?

**Update**

I have an XML file I have a created and validated against an XSD schema (which comes from a 3rd party and is fairly complex).

After loading the XML file as an `XDocument` object, a portion of my code finds places where a new `XElement` instance needs to be added to a parent `XElement` object. Without going into too many details of how this works, I've simplified the concept here:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"path\to\file.xml");
XElement parent = GetElementToAppend(doc);
XElement newElement = new XElement("NewElement",
                          new XAttribute("RequiredAttribute", "value"));
parent.Add(newElement);
```

But instead of simply using the Add method, I need a way to insert my new `XElement` into a valid location. Since I'm adding to a full XML document, the parent could already have many other child elements. So, I would need a way to find the first child element where executing the following code would not cause the `XDocument` to fail schema validation:

```
XElement childElement = FindChildToAdd(parent, newElement);
childElement.AddAfterSelf(newElement);
```

I thought about using the `GetExpectedParticles` method of the `XmlSchemaValidator` class as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823866/xml-schemas-list-allowed-attributes-tags-at-position-in-xml/6827151#6827151), but the implementation seems incredibly complex.

I've also considered doing something like the following to find a valid position in the XML:

```
foreach (XElement el in parent.Elements()) {
    bool errors = false;
    el.AddAfterSelf(newElement);
    newElement.Validate(schemas, (o, e) => { errors = true; });

    if (!errors)
        break;

    newElement.Remove();
}
```

but this seems like it could be incredibly inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be dealing with a very unconstrained model. Most XML applications are able to make some assumptions about the types of XML document that they will be processing ( unless they only need to validate against the provided schema without understanding the content of the document ).

Your application seems to be in the unfortunate position where

a) you do not know the XSD in advance and

b) you need to edit the XML document in a way that is consistent with the XSD

Can I ask what your application is actually trying to do ( unless that information is commercially sensitive - don't get yourself fired on my account )?

If you really need to do this then I think the GetExpectedParticles route is the only option. But don't underestimate the complexity involved in that - it is a genuinely hard problem, and I suspect that it may not be the problem that you *really* need to solve.

Comment: That's what I figured. I have since decided to opt with my original solution of trying to insert the element and validating in a loop. It may be slightly less efficient than parsing the schema with GetExpectedParticles, but I think the trade-off between efficiency and code complexity makes this a no-brainer.

Answer (score 0):

Some context would be useful. What is an 'XElement'?

> But, I want the location of the child element to conform to the rules specified in a given XSD. Specifically, I want the child element to cohere to an rule. It would be nice if I could find a solution that took into account any XSD rules, though.

Please provide examples of the 'rules' that you want to take into account.